# Settings Bundle Not Changing Results

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sdk

Having difficulties with my settings bundle options and the ability to change the settings within my application.

My Plist is structured the following way.

[image: My Plist is structured the following way]

In my viewDidLoad method I have the following:

```
lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.text = @"Hello World";
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
[lbl release];

BOOL changeBG = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"cellSwitched"];
if (changeBG) {
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

The label is changing to black, but never to red. I have tried rebooting the device / reinstalling the app. It seems the switch has no effect.

Comment: How are you getting the information from the plist into `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell

```
(BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"cellSwitched"]
```

will always return NO as I suspect you have no key in your dictionary called **cellSwitched**. It appears in your property list as a value for a key called **key**.

Add a key called **cellSwitched** to your plist and make it of type **Boolean** and give it a value of **YES** or **NO**.

Comment: wouldn't the "key" space in my plist handle putting that within my dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
BOOL changeBG = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"cellSwitched"];
```

You are misusing valueForKey and incorrectly casting the result.

Comment: Hm? Still doesn't seem to work. Am I misusing key in my plist?

Answer (score 0):

"cellSwitched" is currently the contents of a NSString in your dictionary under the key of "key"...

you want to have 'cellSwitched' in the left hand column, not the right hand column.  This entry should have a type of BOOL not string (middle column) and a value of YES or NO in the right hand column...

also, how are you copying this plist into NSUserDefaults ?  It is unusual to have a plist file in the bundle and copy that across, usually most devs in my experience will set individual small objects to [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] at runtime.  Are you aware that a plist file in your bundle is readonly?  I assume you are loading this to an NSDictionary and then saving it inside your sandbox somewhere in order to have read/write privileges to this file.